# Use of phrase "high experience"

Tags: phrases

I read a text translated from Spanish to English. In the English version, they used the phrase "high experience" to describe a specialist in a specific field of medicine. I pointed out that high experience is improper use of English. Was I correct in pointing out their mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Although there are quite a lot of examples of "high experience" on the internet, a lot of them are peripheral usages (often associated with travel and perhaps high-altitude activities).

[These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+high+experience+in%2Cis+highly+experienced+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20highly%20experienced%20in%3B%2Cc0), of *has high experience in* and *is highly experienced in* show a truer picture. The former flatlines. The usage is rare.

Raw Google data supports this:

> "has high experience in": 24 000 hits
>
> "is highly experienced in": 1 350 000 hits (rounding)

The confusion probably arises from the false hope that English is consistent. Both *has wide experience in* and *is widely experienced in* are used ([see these Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+wide+experience+in%2Cis+widely+experienced+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20wide%20experience%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20widely%20experienced%20in%3B%2Cc0)), the latter less frequently ... and 'has high experience in' has faultless grammar. Never trust the English (I think that's originally a French expression, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfidious_Albion)).

Whether or not to use it? I'd choose the apparently vastly preferred variant.

Answer (score 0):

In context and with correct grammar, the words **high experience** could be used in English:

There are many usages, here is but one: [Nat. Lib. of Medicine](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16916159)

> Attention in athletes of **high and low experience** engaged in different
>   open skill sports.